# Lost portion of the hard drive

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, window

Is there any way to see the partitions of the hard disks?
Problem is I had two OS in my system, but once I upgraded Windows 7 to Windows 8, I was not able to access another one (Ubuntu).

Now my system had an internal memory of 300 GB but now total uses able memory is only 250 GB (50 GB was used to install Ubuntu).

Is there any way to access that lost part or to access Ubuntu again?

Even though I have Degraded back to Windows 7 and formatted the whole C drive there is still problem.
I used some of the methods like using command (`diskpart`) in cmd, but it only gives portions and sizes inside the window it self.
I have only option of formatting the whole hard drive. Is there any other option to utilize that space?

Comment: try booting from a live linux cd and see if you can access the partition from there (e.g. Ubuntu comes with gparted).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By upgrading to Windows 8 the installer has rewritten the start of the disk (that contains the bootloader) and it can only see your Windows 8 install. As Gotschi has written, boot to your Ubuntu disk which should be able to see your Ubuntu partition. You have two options; keep using the Ubuntu LiveCD to see data, or, if you want to be able to boot Ubuntu, you need to use the Ubuntu CD to replace the bootloader with GRUB. This will give you the option on boot to choose Windows or Ubuntu.

An alternative option,  if this is too daunting, is to extend your Windows 8 partition to use the entire disk (erasing Ubuntu) and install Ubuntu as a virtual machine inside your Windows 8 using, say, VirtualBox. You can then run Ubuntu inside Windows 8 at the same time!

Comment: thanks buddy but can you tell me how i can do that second part, how i can extend partition.

Comment: 1. Boot to Windows. 2. Go to Desktop view. 3. Right click "Computer" icon on desktop. 4. Click "Manage" from submenu. 5. When Computer Management console opens click "Disk Management". 6. You will probably see an unknown partition of approx 50GB (this is your Ubuntu partition) - Right click it and click "Delete Volume" (if enabled) otherwise click "Format" - This will remove your Ubuntu install!! 7. Once the partition has been removed you will see it as "Unallocated". 8. Right click your "C:" and click "Extend" from the menu. 9. Follow the instructions to extend the partition.

Comment: BUT ALWAYS, ALWAYS make sure you've got a backup of your important files - just in case you have to re-install Windows 8.

Comment: Look for VirtualBox (install the guest addons too) and install it. Then you create your virtual machine (VM) and you can boot to an Ubuntu ISO and it'll install as if you were preparing your own physical PC.